# MVC -DropDownList - Categories - SubCategories

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my database I have  tbales: categoreis and SubCategoreis. I would Like to create one Dropdownlist containg both of these. Something like:

«Välj»

```
<option value='1000' style='background-color:#dcdcc3;font-weight:bold;' id='cat1000' >

            -- FORDON --    /// this is from Categoreis Table

    </option> 

<option value='1020'  id='cat1020' >
        Bilar                    /// this is from SubCategoreis

    </option> 

<option value='1040'  id='cat1040' >
        Bildelar & Biltillbehör   /// this is from Categoreis

    </option> 

<option value='1060'  id='cat1060' >
        Båtar                   /// this is from Categoreis

    </option> 

<option value='1080'  id='cat1080' >
        Båtdelar & tillbehör   /// this is from Categoreis

    </option>
```

Any samples how I could solve this? should I use Helpers or MVCUsercontrol??? I think that caching is importatnt in this case.Help me out !
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Just load the data in the controller and structure it as you see fit ... then all you need to do is pass the list to the dropdown html helper and it doesn't have to know anything about the data's structure.

If you embrace the separation of concerns that is afforded to you when you fully buy into the MVC pattern, this sort of thing answers itself :-P

Answer (score 0):

Frajer,

You need to create a SELECT list with OPTION and OPTGROUP elements.  Here is the format of what you are looking for:

```
<select>
<option value="">[Please select an option]</option>
<optgroup label="Group 1">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Group 2">
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Group 3">
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="6">Option 6</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Group 4">
    <option value="7">Option 7</option>
    <option value="8">Option 8</option>
</optgroup>
```

Check this blog post. It shows categories in bold and category items in regular text. The author creates an MVC extension to handle this.

http://weblogs.asp.net/raduenuca/archive/2011/02/26/asp-net-mvc-extending-the-dropdownlist-to-show-the-items-grouped-by-a-category.aspx