# Create Subcategories in MVC dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, selectlist

I am trying to create groupings in my dropdownlist like following:

> New Media
>   --Category 1
>   --Category 2
>   Technician
>   --Category 3
>   --Category 4

I have found this old [MVC -DropDownList - Categories - SubCategories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971059/mvc-dropdownlist-categories-subcategories) but that is before this was included in to MVC.  Then I came across this [HTML “optgroup” support in DropDownList](http://www.kashyapas.com/2014/06/09/html-ldquooptgrouprdquo-support-in-dropdownlist-asp-net-mvc-5-2/) . So with those two links I modified the code to look like this:

```
ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories.Where(c => c.Status == 1).OrderBy(c => c.CategoryName), "CategoryId", "CategoryName", "RoleId", 3);
```

The problem is that it is showing the Guid from that table, not the RoleDescription field which I need. I tried modifying the "RoleId" to be "Role" because that is what my virtual class is in the model (referencing the Role class).  How do I change this so it pulls the correct role Name?

Comment: Can you post an image of the output you're receiving?

Comment: You need to show the models - `"RoleId"` would need to be something like `"Role.RoleDescription"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, that worked.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I have updated the answer by Nava - Prev. Queti so you can accept and close this out

Answer (score 1):

The `dataGroupField` is used as both the field to group by and also what to display. Since you passed in the RoleId, it is grouping by this field and displaying the RoleId for each group.

You'll need to change it so that you pass in the RoleDescription field as the third parameter.

```
ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories.Where(c => c.Status == 1)
    .OrderBy(c => c.CategoryName), "CategoryId", "CategoryName", "Role.RoleDescription ", 3);
```

Based on the query you are currently doing, I have a feeling you'll need to reference a navigation property from `db.Categories` or do a join in order to get the `RoleDescription`